# URL for guest access to a Linux Samba server share from Finder

Tags: finder, smb

What is the correct URL for connecting as Guest to a Linux Samba server share from OS X?

Example:

- From Finder, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
- Enter url: `smb://192.168.1.100/shared_files`

Answer (score 5):

The answer seems to be to use username and password `guest`:

```
smb://guest:guest@192.168.1.100/shared_files
```